# c++ string iterator

Tags: c++, string, iterator

I'm trying to do an if statement inside a loop with an iterator over a string, but can't figure out how to get the current character for the if statement:

```
for (std::string::iterator i=buffer.end()-1; i>=buffer.begin(); --i) {
    if (!isalpha(*i) && !isdigit(*i)) {
        if(i != "-") { // obviously this is wrong
            buffer.erase(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me get the current character so I can do some additional if statements?

Comment: you don't really need the isalpha and isdigit check if you are going to check for a specific character right afterward

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to get the current character

You do it twice here:

```
if (!isalpha(*i) && !isdigit(*i))
```

When you dereference an iterator (`*i`), you get the element to which it points.

```
"-"
```

This is a string literal, not a character.  Character constants use single quotes, e.g., `'-'`.

```
for (std::string::iterator i=buffer.end()-1; i>=buffer.begin(); --i)
```

This would be much simpler with reverse iterators:

```
for (std::string::reverse_iterator i = buffer.rbegin(); i != buffer.rend(); ++i)
```

Comment: if((*i) != '-')) in case you need more clarification

Comment: @P.R.:  Good catch on the `"-"`.

Comment: @James Thank you :) I used to be a lab instructor for a C++ course and I guess now the first things my eyes go to are the '' and ==

Comment: Using a `reverse_iterator` will be simpler for the iteration, but it will be less simple to `erase` elements.

Comment: @David Rodríguez While using a forward iterator makes `erase` simpler, it also makes the loop illegal because it will decrement the iterator to before `begin`.

Comment: @Mark:  The loop is illegal either way due to the `erase`.  +1 to you for catching that and recommending `remove_if`.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(i != "-")
```

should be

```
if(*i != '-')
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the character just say `*i`, but this isn't enough. Your loop isn't legal because it's not allowed to decrement before `begin`. You should use reverse iterators or the `remove_if` algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have solved the particular issue that you have, but you should be aware that there are different approaches to solve your actual problem: *erase elements that fullfill a condition*. That can be easily solved with the *remove/erase* idiom:

```
// C++0x enabled compiler
str.erase( 
    std::remove_if( str.begin(), str.end(), 
                  [](char ch) { return !isalpha(ch) && !isdigit(ch) && ch != '-' } ),
    str.end() );
```

While this might look cumbersome at first, once you have seen it a couple of times it will no longer be surprising, and it is an effective way of deleting elements from a vector or string.

If your compiler does not have lambda support, then you can create a functor and pass it as the third argument to `remove_if`:

```
// at namespace level, sadly c++03 does not allow you to use local classes in templates
struct mycondition {
   bool operator()( char ch ) const {
      return !isalpha(ch) && !isdigit(ch) && ch != '-';
   }
};
// call:
str.erase( 
    std::remove_if( str.begin(), str.end(), mycondition() ),
    str.end() );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have it right above in the previous `if` statement: `i` is an iterator, so `*i` gives the character referred to by the iterator.

Note that if you're going to iterate through a collection backwards, it's generally easier to use a `reverse_iterator` with `rbegin` and `rend`. I'd probably use a pre-packaged algorithm instead though.